# call a method from finally section of $http in angular

Tags: angularjs

I want call a mthod from finally, by copying allProduct function to finally my problem will be solved ,but i want call this method

```
app.controller('productController', function($scope, $http) {

$scope.allProduct = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: $.param({'type' : 'allProduct' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data){           
        $scope.products = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
        $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });
}
$scope.saveProduct = function(){

    var productName = $scope.nProductName;        
    var productCode = $scope.nProductCode;
    var productImage = $scope.nProductImage;
    var productCategory = $scope.nProductCategory;
    var details = tinymce.activeEditor.getContent();    

    $http({            
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: $.param({'type' : 'saveProduct',
            'productName':productName,
            'productCode':productCode,
            'productImage':productImage,
            'productCategory': productCategory,                
            'productDetails':details}),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data){            
        $scope.products = data;
    })
    .error(function() {
        $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    })
    .finally(allProduct);
}});
```

how to call allProduct method from finally??

Comment: $scope.allProduct. Also note that success and error are deprecated for quite a while now. Use then().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JB Nizet mentions, success/error are deprecated.  You should use then/catch to chain your promises.  Check the $http doc: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

I would declare your "allProducts" callback as a function then reference it when you need it in your controller, like this:

```
$scope.allProduct = allProductCallback;

$scope.saveProduct = function(){
    ...
    })
    .then(function(data){            
        $scope.products = data;
    })
    .catch(function() {
        $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    })
    .finally(allProductCallback);
}});

function allProductCallback(){
    $http({
        method: 'post',
        url: 'ajax.php',
        data: $.param({'type' : 'allProduct' }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(data){           
        $scope.products = data;
    })
    .catch(function() {
        $scope.data = "error in fetching data";
    });
}
```